# How do you implement generic factory interface?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, generics

I'm using [DbContextScope](https://github.com/mehdime/DbContextScope). I'm trying to implement this generic interface:

```
namespace EntityFramework.DbContextScope.Interfaces {
    public interface IDbContextFactory {
        TDbContext CreateDbContext<TDbContext>() where TDbContext : class, IDbContext;
    }
}
```

The goal is to provide my implementation to the following function:

```
namespace EntityFramework.DbContextScope {
    public class DbContextScope : IDbContextScope, IDisposable {
        public DbContextScope(IDbContextFactory dbContextFactory);
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to implement this interface and provide it to the DbContextScope properly. I tried a generic implementation:

```
public class MyDbContextContextFactoryGeneric : IDbContextFactory {
    TDbContext IDbContextFactory.CreateDbContext<TDbContext>() {
        Type type = typeof(TDbContext);
        if (type == typeof(MyDbContext)) {
            return new MyDbContext();
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But the error I get is: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyDBContext' to 'TDbContext'".

I tried an explicit implementation:

```
public class MyDbContextContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<MyDBContext> {
    public MyDBContext Create() {
        return new MyDBContext();
    }
}
```

But when I try to pass it to the DbContextScope like this:

```
public class Test {
    public void PerformTest() {
        IDbContextFactory dbContextFactory = new MyDbContextContextFactory();
        using (DbContextScope scope = new DbContextScope(dbContextFactory)) {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error on the line before the using line: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyDbContextContextFactory' to 'EntityFramework.DbContextScope.Interfaces.IDbContextFactory'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the correct syntax and was able to solve it using the generic approach.

```
public class MyDbContextContextFactoryGeneric : IDbContextFactory {
    TDbContext IDbContextFactory.CreateDbContext<TDbContext>() {
        return typeof(TDbContext) == typeof(MyDbContext)
          ? new MyDbContext() as TDbContext
          : Activator.CreateInstance<TDbContext>();
    }
}
```